# Curved Color in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to add a curved feedback with diff color like in the pic attached.[image: Panel] I tried multiple options but I am unable to do it .

Here's the (simplified) HTML source:

```
<form id="TopPanelForm">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="mnLinks">

                <div class="right userInfo">
                    Logged in user:&nbsp; <strong>[username]</strong>|
                    <a href="#">About</a>|
                    <a href="#">Sign Out</a>|
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;text-align: left;background-color:red;">Feedback</a>                        
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

But I am unable to do it . Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: please, please, stop using tables for layout. Will cause you all sorts of issues further down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use border-radius to make the curved feedback.

```
<form id="TopPanelForm">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="mnLinks">

                <div class="right userInfo">
                    Logged in user:&nbsp; <strong>[username]</strong>|
                    <a href="#">About</a>|
                    <a href="#">Sign Out</a>|
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;text-align: left; background: red; border-bottom-left-radius: 100px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Calibri, Corbel, Arial; color: #FFF; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #000;">Feedback</a>                        
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Now you can add a css gradient using this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

**EDIT**

To put it at top use `position: relative;` to table, and `position: absolute;` to "Feedback"

```
<form id="TopPanelForm">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position: relative;">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="mnLinks">

                <div class="right userInfo">
                    Logged in user:&nbsp; <strong>[username]</strong>|
                    <a href="#">About</a>|
                    <a href="#">Sign Out</a>|
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;text-align: left; background: red; border-bottom-left-radius: 100px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Calibri, Corbel, Arial; color: #FFF; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #000; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;">Feedback</a>                        
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks . This works great . The only problem is that feedback comes in same line as logout and not on top

Comment: To put it at top use position: relative; to table, and position: absolute; to "Feedback" - Check my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use border radius for this sort of thing.

```
border-radius: 0 0 0 100%; /*change 100% to desired percentage*/
```

---

```css
.feedback {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 90%;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback">Feedback?</div>
```

---

As a side note, however, i would like to point out a few things:

- Please don't use tables for layout (it causes multiple issues further down the line)
- Please avoid inline styling (we have css stylesheets for a reason)